# LightDM: how to distinguish users with the same name?

Tags: lightdm

I am using LightDM with the [Slick Greeter](https://github.com/linuxmint/slick-greeter). In my system, I have two user accounts for myself. They have the same *name*, but different *user names*. I want to separate private and professional work.

Problem: in the greeter, there is no visual difference between them. I only see the *name* (not the *user name*).

Hacky solutions:

- know the order of the accounts
- use different window managers (because they have different icons and they are visible next to the *user name*)

Obviously, all of the above solutions are plain out stupid. Better ideas? I am willing to change the greeter, but not the the session manager LightDM, neither my *names* (because they are used in other programs, such as email).

Comment: AFAICG from the [source](https://github.com/linuxmint/slick-greeter/blob/ae927483c5dcf3ae898b3f0849e3770cfa04afa1/src/user-list.vala#L1049) there's no option to change which names "slick-greeter" displays. You may try to recompile it, then `apt-mark hold`, etc ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your avatar:

create the image file as `/home/username/.face`

from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Changing_your_avatar

Comment: It seems that Slick Greeter theme does not show avatars.

Comment: @BlueManCZ is right. Nevertheless, using the face icons to distinguish the accounts is a workable solution that meets all my requirements. I ended up using the `lightdm-gtk-greeter`.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is not to have the same names, e.g.

`John Doe A`
`John Doe Z`

Comment: Yes, that would technically work, but is not what I am looking for (see the end of my question). Thank you though :-)